# How do I fix "cannot find -lccp4c" to install Gromacs with Density Fit?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, cuda, libraries, cmake

I am trying to install gromacs 5.0.7 with automated desnity fitting according to the protocol provided at the bottom of this link: https://www.mpibpc.mpg.de/grubmueller/densityfitting

Unfortunately, I do not know where to start installing the ccp4 portion, and starting installing it only after getting to the "make" portion.

After "make", I get the following error:

```
[ 97%] Building C object src/gromacs/CMakeFiles/libgromacs.dir/utility/baseversion-gen.c.o
[ 97%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libgromacs.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lccp4c
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/gromacs/CMakeFiles/libgromacs.dir/build.make:17155: recipe for target 'lib/libgromacs.so.0.0.0' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/libgromacs.so.0.0.0] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1460: recipe for target 'src/gromacs/CMakeFiles/libgromacs.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/gromacs/CMakeFiles/libgromacs.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

If you could all help me with this, I would appreciate it very much.

**Edit 1-Update using Eliah'a Answer**

After installing libccp4 using

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libccp4-dev
```

I still got an error code, so installed installing fftw using

```
sudo apt-get install fftw3 fftw3-dev pkg-config
```

After this, I then when to source file and used `make`, and it compiled through 100%! I then did `make check`, and that seemed to work.

After this, I tried to install and got the following error:

```
    bys@bys-Precision-Tower-3620:~/Desktop/gromacs-5.0.7-densfit/build$ sudo make install
[  0%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/gromacs/gmxlib/cuda_tools/CMakeFiles/cuda_tools.dir/cuda_tools_generated_pmalloc_cuda.cu.o
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_20'
CMake Error at cuda_tools_generated_pmalloc_cuda.cu.o.Release.cmake:219 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/bys/Desktop/gromacs-5.0.7-densfit/build/src/gromacs/gmxlib/cuda_tools/CMakeFiles/cuda_tools.dir//./cuda_tools_generated_pmalloc_cuda.cu.o


src/gromacs/gmxlib/cuda_tools/CMakeFiles/cuda_tools.dir/build.make:77: recipe for target 'src/gromacs/gmxlib/cuda_tools/CMakeFiles/cuda_tools.dir/cuda_tools_generated_pmalloc_cuda.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/gromacs/gmxlib/cuda_tools/CMakeFiles/cuda_tools.dir/cuda_tools_generated_pmalloc_cuda.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1503: recipe for target 'src/gromacs/gmxlib/cuda_tools/CMakeFiles/cuda_tools.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/gromacs/gmxlib/cuda_tools/CMakeFiles/cuda_tools.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I figure this is an error involving Nvidia CUDA toolkit and Drivers.
How should I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

**Install the `libccp4-dev` package.** [The package should be available for whatever Ubuntu release you're using.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libccp4-dev&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) One good way to install it is to run:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libccp4-dev
```

The `libccp4-dev` package directly provides the header files for the CCP4 libraries, which you need in order to compile software that uses them, and also declares dependencies on the other packages that provide the library binaries and data files, causing them to be installed too. That includes the `libccp4c0` package that provides the binaries you're linking against.

Then, to build Gromacs with Density Fit, I recommend you go to the top-level source directory (i.e., the directory that was created when you unpacked the archive) and run:

```bash
rm -r build  # omit if you already deleted the old build directory
mkdir build
cd build
CCP4INC=/usr/include/ccp4/
cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-I $CCP4INC" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-I $CCP4INC"
make
```

(For a parallel build you might use `make -j5` or something instead of just `make`. For *`N`* parallel jobs, use `make -jN`.)

This is similar to and based on the instructions at [the bottom of that page](https://www.mpibpc.mpg.de/grubmueller/densityfitting), but I didn't bother to specify where the actual library binaries are. It was able to find those itself. I tested this on Ubuntu 19.10, which as of this writing is the development release (i.e., not yet released) so you wouldn't be running that on a production system. But I expect this to work on earlier releases as well. You might not even have to tell it where the headers are--usually that's not necessary either, for libraries installed with the system's package manager--but I *did* need to do that.

If you do end up needing to specify the library locations, you can do that by adding `-DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, assuming your system is a PC or Mac with a 64-bit Intel or AMD processor, running the 64-bit version of Ubuntu.

All together, the `cmake` command would be:

```bash
cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-I $CCP4INC" -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-I $CCP4INC"
```

I tested that, too, on the same system, and it also worked, with the subsequent `make` succeeding.

---

Below are some tips for finding packages that provide libraries, even when you don't know the name of any particular file in the library, as often occurs when you attempt to download and build software and the build fails because it can't find the library.

In general, packages that exist to provide libraries have names that start with `lib` followed by the name of the library. The `apt list` command accepts globs, in which `*` in a package name represents a sequence of zero or more of any character. In this case, `apt list 'libccp4c*'` would have been imperfect, because it doesn't list the relevant dev package.

I tend to search for the smallest important-seeming substring of a library name that seems like it might narrow things down enough, and then follow up with a larger substring if there are too many results to skim quickly. I happened to start by running `apt list '*ccp4*'`, which found exactly what I was looking for on the first try.

Then I ran `apt show libccp4-dev` to make sure it was what I thought it was, and `apt -s install libccp4-dev` to see what *would* be installed without actually doing the installation.

After installing the package, I ran `dpkg-query -L libccp4-dev | grep -F cmaplib.h` to find what directory contains the CCP4 headers, because I happened to see an error message in a previous build attempt that mentioned that file. Otherwise I could have run `dpkg-query -L libccp4-dev` and inspected a bit more output.

I didn't end up needing to find the directory that contained the library binaries (see above), whose names tend to end in `so`, sometimes folllowed by a `.`-delimited sequence of numerals. But if I had needed to, `dpkg-query -L libccp4c0` would have done it.

Comment: Thank, this got me through 100 percent of the make and make check step. After trying to install, the following script, shown above under edits in the original post, occurred.

Comment: @JosephNoble I couldn't reproduce that, but it looks like [nvcc fatal : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_20](https://askubuntu.com/q/960238). `cmake` should've given details about CUDA. I recommend giving either the full output of the `cmake` command or just the portion about CUDA. Do you want GROMACS to use CUDA, or would configuring the build not to use it at all be okay? Also, GROMACS 2018 with density fit is available too, and I suspect that might work better with CUDA with recent hardware and drivers. Do you need GROMACS 5.0.7? I suggest adding all this information to your question.